# Prove that the entire underlying set in a Peano System with the strict order relation($<$) forms a unique strictly ascending sequence

Tags: solution-verification, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

**Original question:** Prove that $1<2<3<4$,etc in a Peano System

That is the definition of Peano system by the used textbook.

**Peano Systems:** By a Peano System we mean a set $P$, a particular element 1 in $P$, and a singulary operation $S$ on $P$ such that the following axioms are satisfied.

$(P1)$: 1 is not the successor $S(x)$ of any object $x$ in $P$. In symbols, $(\forall x)(S(x) \neq 1)$.

$(P2)$: Different objects in $P$ have different successors. This can be formulated as follows:
$$(\forall x)(\forall y)(x \neq y \Rightarrow S(x) \neq S(y))$$.
$(P3)$: Principle of Mathematical Induction: Any subset of P containing $1$ and closed under the successor operation must be identical with $P$. This can be symbolically rendered as follows:
$$(\forall B)([B \subseteq P \land 1 \in B \land (\forall x)(x \in B \Rightarrow S(x)\in B)]\Rightarrow P=B)$$

Such a Peano system will be denoted by a ordered triple $(P,S,1)$, $P$ is called the **underlying set**, $S$ the **successor operation**, and $1$ the **distinguished element**.

Consider a standard Peano System $(\mathbb{N},S,1)$, where $S:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is defined as $S(x) = x+1$, and we have the following theorems.

1. $(\forall x)(x=1 \lor (\exists y)(x = S(y))$
2. $(\forall x)(S(x) \neq x)$
3. x < S(x)
4. $\lnot(\exists y)(x < y < S(x))$
5. $x \neq 1 \Rightarrow $ 1 < x

$x<y$ is defined as a shorthand for $(\exists z)(x+z = y)$.

We have addition defined also, with commutative, associative and cancellation law.

**edit 3**

As the question got considered ambiguous because the usage of "..." or "etc",  I tried to do some reasearch seeking for what could be the meaning of "$1<2<3<4$,etc", and as I stated in a commentary, this exercise is present in a section about order relation. Thus I started looking for order properties and related definitions.

First I reached a paper about [relations](http://web.mit.edu/neboat/Public/6.042/relations.pdf) where the author a give quick explanation about order relations and show the equivalence between a Partially-ordered sets(poset) and Directed Acyclic Graphs(DAG). In section 4.1 and 4.2 it is presented a Theorem which states that a "poset has no directed cycles other than self-loops.

The previous mentioned paper show a pattern $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq a_3 \leq a_4 ...$ which is similar to the pattern stated in the question but its not the same. From this point I tried to found the difference from orders which is established with $<$ instead of $\leq$. Then I found the definition about [strict and non strict partial orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders), where the DAG got related to strict order $<$.

But after this point I wanted to understand what is the difference between the total and partial order, thus it made me to reach the wikipedia page about total order, which in fact have a little section defining [chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Chains) as: "The term chain is a synonym for a totally ordered set" and a more specific case, **Ascending Chain** as "totally ordered set having a (unique) minimal element", from this section I have gone to the definition of [Ascending Chain Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition#Definition) which states in the first line the assertion the non existence of a **strictly ascending sequence** $a_1<a_2<a_3...$

Taking a look on some definitions as [strictly ascending order](https://planetmath.org/ascendingorder) or [strictly increasing sequence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Strictly_Increasing/Sequence). I have found they all capture the same concept as strictly ascending sequence which capture the same concept stated by the author of the original question.

Thus I think the question can be stated in a non ambigous way, and Im changing the title according to those findings.

From "Prove "$1<2<3<4$",etc" to "Prove that the entire underlying set in a Peano System with strict order relation($<$) forms a unique strictly ascending sequence".

**end edit 3**

Here is my atempt:

From $(5)$ its clear that $(\forall x)(1<x)$, thus the order starts with,

$1 < x$, where from $(1)$, $x=1 \lor (\exists u)(x = S(u))$, if we assume $x \neq 1$ then by $(3,4)$ we have also that $u<S(u)$ and no one element in $\mathbb{N}$ is between $u$ and $S(u)$.

Now if we take $S(S(u))$ we have also by (3,4) that $S(u) < S(S(u))$ and there is no element between them. Thus for any $x \neq 1$ we have $x=S(u)$ where $u < S(u) < S(S(u))$.

If we let $x=S(1)$ or $2$ we get: $1 < S(1) < S(S(1))$, or $1 < 2 < 3$.

If we let $x=S(S(1))$ or $3$ we get $S(1) < S(S(1)) < S(S(S(1)))$, or $2<3<4$

By $(5)$ we have that $4<1)$

Thus if we let $x=4$ we get $3<4<5$,

By $(5)$ we have that $1<5$ and by transitivity of $<$ when $x=3$ we have that $[2<3 \land 3<4]\Rightarrow 2<4$, but if $[2<4 \land 4<5] \Rightarrow 2<5$

Thus we have $1<2<3<4<5...$

**Edit 1 begin**

I noticed using the definition of $<$, that if $x < y$ then there we have $x+p = y$ for some $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and from this we have that $S(x+p) = S(y)$, thus $(x+p)+1 = s(y)$ and from commutativity a associativity of addition $(x+1) + p = s(y)$, so $S(x) + p = S(y)$ then by definition $S(x) < S(y)$, so $x<y \Rightarrow S(x) < S(y)$.

Here is we start from $1<2$ which is true by $(5)$, and from previous conclusion $1<2 \Rightarrow 2<3$, but if $2<3$ then $3<4$...

I still not knowing how to avoid the (...)

**Edit 1 end**

**Edit 2 begin**
Here Im trying another approach which follows from the idea on edit 1.

First we have that $x<S(x)$, by (3), from this we know that $x+p = S(x)$ for some $p$ in $\mathbb{N}$, namely $p=1$, from this we have that $S(x+p) = S(S(x))$ and then $S(x)+p = S(S(x))$, so by definition of $<$ we have that $S(x)<S(S(x))$ and therefore $x<S(x) \Rightarrow S(x)<S(S(x))$.

We have that $1<S(1)$ since $1+1=S(1)$, thus if we take a initial segment $I_n$ from $\mathbb{N}$ from $1$ up to $n$. Lets say $n=4$ we have defined $I_4 = \{1,2,3,4\}$ First we have that $1<2$ is true by (5) then we have that $1<2 \Rightarrow 2<3 \Rightarrow 3<4$. It can be encoded as $(1<2) \land (2<3) \land (3<4)$ from this follows that $1<2<3<4$.

Now let $A = \{x : x \in \mathbb{N} \land x < S(x)\}$, first we have that $1 \in A$ since $1 \in A \land 1 < S(1)$, now we assume that $x \in A$, thus we have that $x \in \mathbb{N} \land x<S(x)$, but we have that $x<S(x) \Rightarrow S(x) < S(S(x))$, then $S(x) \in A$. We have show that $x \in A \Rightarrow S(x) \in A$. then by mathematical induction $A = \mathbb{N}$.

As we have $x<S(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{N}$, now we take the some initial segment $I_n$ of $\mathbb{N}$ from 1 up to $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and we have that $1<2<3<4,etc$ holds true in $I_n$, where $etc$ goes up to $n$, as $n$ is arbitrary $1<2<3<4,etc$ holds true in $\mathbb{N}$.

**Edit 2 end**

I think the same proccess can be repeated using all $x \neq 1$ in $\mathbb{N}$, but the usage of $...$(dots) turn what I need to do imprecise, so how Im supposed to do this proof?

Comment: What are you trying to prove? You could argue that the statement "$1<2<3<\dots$" is just an informal way of saying "$(\forall n)(n < S(n))$, which is then just precisely statement 3. Otherwise, you have to be more precise with what you mean by "$1<2<3<\dots$".

Comment: The exercise says "Prove: 1<2<3<4,etc." I interpreted the author wants a proof that this will holds true following this order 1,S(1),S(S(1).... for all elements in the Peano System.

I already thinked about statment 3, but its no precise about successor of some element being great than all predecessors.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase: you have to get rid of the "..." in the statement of the theorem or else it's hard to be clear what it is you're trying to show in the first place. Can you rephrase the theorem in first-order logic without the use of "..." or "etc"?

Comment: Im trying to think way, but as I said the author put this "etc" which leads to this confusion. I think what should be proved is "$(\forall x)(1<=x) ..$ Im stucked here but maybe you can help me put it into first-order logic, I think what he mean is to prove that no number is small than $1$ and for every number $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ we have the property of can put the elements in increasing order from 1 up to $n$ without any number between the number and his successor.

Comment: What textbook are you using?

Comment: @Shaun Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis by Elliot Mendelson.


Im at Chapter 2, Topic of Order Relation, on page 67, exercise 7.

Comment: To me it seems like $ \forall x \forall n (x<\overbrace{S(S(S(\ldots S}^{n\text{ times}}(x)))\ldots)$

Comment: Or $\forall x \forall n \forall y<n,(\overbrace{S(S(S\ldots}^{n\text{ times}}(x)\ldots)> \overbrace{S(S(S\ldots}^{y\text{ times}}(x)\ldots)$

Comment: But, The axioms you presented can’t disprove the existence of some element $u$ bigger then one and all the other natural numbers with infinite “wells” of numbers on both of it’s sides.

Comment: What do you mean by infinite "wells"?

Comment: You may wish to look into [nonstandard models of PA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic).

Comment: What I mean is that  it could be so $1<2<3<4\ldots$.  $\ldots \omega -2 < \omega -1 < \omega < \omega + 1 <\omega+2 \ldots$  Which is not a unique strictly ascending sequence as there doesn’t exist a bijection between it and $\mathbb N$

Comment: But how It coult be present in a Peano system where all objects have a sucessor and its impossible to have another object between the object and its successor?

Can you give a proof on how some of those "wells" can be formed even with the presence of Theorems 1,2,3,4,5 ?

Those $\omega$'s are objects in the Peano system?

If it is the case so all those objects have the same properties and a "wells" cannot be formed, because for every object it will have a successor and no object between itself and his successor, as well by (1) it is a successor or is $1$.

Comment: @dwolfeu Thanks for the resource, At this exercise it is assumed a Standard Peano system, but i will take a look on the resource.

Comment: I added the definition of Peano system along with 3 axioms used in the book, I still cant see how the "wells" can be formed, I know this question started ambiguous and got edited a lot of times, so Thanks for you all which still trying to understand and keep helping.

Comment: True, nonstanadrd models are perhaps tangential to your question, although do note that one cannot assume a standard model of PA from just the axioms of PA alone (nor from the five sentences you list at the start of your question).

Comment: Proving the axioms  1. Pretty obvious, $S(\omega + (n -1)) = \omega +n$  2. Obvious.  3.In all cases, $z=1$.  4.because any part of the “wells” is the natural numbers shifted.  5. $z=\omega +(n-1)$

Comment: These “wells” aren’t a consequence of Peano arithmetic, they are neither provable nor disprovable from the axioms.

Comment: But if these "wells" arent a consequence of Peano arithmetic and the are neither provable nor disprovable from the Peano axioms, it is not possible to prove that the natural numbers is a stricly ascending sequence just from Peano axioms?

Comment: @razivo Sorry if a did this big confusion, but the 5 enumerated statements from the start of question are five theorems and the Axioms are just the 3 (P1),(P2),(P3), in this case it still the same about the presence of the "wells"?

Comment: Oh, I get it, P3 restricts the set to be the natural numbers, the “wells” are impossible. You can prove it because (P3) implies that $P$ is closed under succession, and axioms (P3) and (P2) imply theorem 4, letting you construct and prove that the strictly descending sequence actually contains all of $P$.

Comment: I think you mean 'ascending' in your last comment, because every strictly descending sequence in P will be finite because the Least Number Principle. From the answer you posted I just assumed this was just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s prove that $<a_i>$
Where:
$a_0=1$
$a_i=S(a_{i-1})$
is a strictly ascending  sequence.
We need to prove two things:

1. It is strictly increasing, clear consequence of theorem $(3)$.
2. It is the entire set $P$, this can be proven by axiom 3, $<a_i>$ contains one and is closed under succession($S(a_i)=a_{i+1}$) by definition.

Comment: You agree with me that saying in the standard Peano system $(\mathbb{N},S,1)$ where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers $\{1,2,3,4,...\}$, proving that $1<2<3<4,etc$ is the same of proving that $\mathbb{N}$ along with $<$(strict order relation), forms a unique strictly ascending sequence?

Comment: Yes, thus is what I did, just replace $P$ with $\mathbb N$ if you are confused.